# Adding content to wordpress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So, i finally got my css and js scripts to load on WP

Now there is but one thing i need to get done.

i have my own theme, including header.php, footer.php, page.php

header.php and footer.php is working just fine, loading scripts and showing properly, but now i need to add all the other content.

my page.php is currently:

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I would need to somehow add html content to pages, i have about 20 ready made .php pages which needs to be transfered to WP.

Soooo how do i go about making new page (pages -> add new) and using page template while getting the html content to show up?

I've tried to just make new page and in text mode add up all the html into page, but it only shows empty page with header and footer, so the problem is most likely the page.php and i have no idea how to get it to work.

Comment: If you want raw html in the page, you can just create new page and put your html into the page content (in the text area / editor) in the text mode (in the upper-rightmost of the editor as opposed to the visual mode) so that it can save and render the html.

Comment: you need the loop first before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do look like this:

```
<?php /* Template Name: CustomPageT1 */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php   
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        the_content();
    endwhile; 
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the good way. While developing a custom theme from scratch is a great challenge it's not too hard.

I could recommend to take it easy and follow this tutorial I found really helpful some time ago, I learned a lot there:

[Developing a WordPress Theme from Scratch](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/)

You must have the official source documentation always in your mind:

[Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)

Do some reading and you will see that making themes is really fun and gratifying :)

EDIT:
I would recommend picking a good starter theme or framework and work using [child themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You have plenty of them to pick.

Answer (score 1):

1. To get started adding a new page to your WordPress site, find the Pages menu in the WordPress Dashboard Navigation menu. Click Add new.

The WordPress page editor looks nearly identical to the post editor, except for a few different boxes located on the right side of the screen.

2. Add the title of the page, like About. Note: If you have pretty permalinks set up, the title of your page will also be the URL slug.
3. Next, add some content.
4. The Publish section of the page editor is exactly the same as for writing posts. When you’re ready to publish, you can either publish immediately, save this or a draft, or schedule the page to be published later.
5. The Page Attributes section applies a parent page and template to your new page. For the Parent section, you can arrange your pages into hierarchies. For example, you could create this new page with additional pages under it. There are no limits to how many levels you can nest pages.
6. Some WordPress themes have custom page templates, so the next Template section allows you to apply a template to your new page.
7. The Order box allows you to order your page numerically. Pages are usually ordered alphabetically, but you can choose your own order by entering a number in this field.
8. Preview the page one last time, then click Publish. You’ve added a new page to your WordPress site.

This is how your 
your **index.php** should look like :

```
<?php
 get_header();?>

<div class="YourContainer">

 <div class="Whatever">
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="ContentSectionDiv">

   <?php the_content();?>

  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
 </div>
</div>


 <?php get_footer();?>
```

Comment: added that piece of code to my page.php and it actualy works! htank you so much :)

Comment: okey... it worke'd for a minute, perfectly aaaand now it's back to not loading any css or images....

Comment: @Clomez did you enqued scripts using functions.php or?

Comment: i added index.php and now all of my resources are 404 and the url is now index.php/aboutus and nothing showes up.

Comment: i was loading all the css and js from wp-content/themes/project/css & /js

Comment: @Clomez what's the differnce in this code that u have unmarked and the one you marked?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can make also a custom loop
 <?php
 $arg = array("post_type" => "services",
                "posts_per_page" => 9,
                "order_by" => "date",
                "order" => "ASC",

            );

            $services = new WP_Query($arg);
            if ($services->have_posts()):;

            while ($services->have_posts()):$services->the_post();
                the_content();             
               endwhile;
            endif;
            ?>
```